# How do I send tez to my smart contract?

Tags: transactions, storage

I would like to send tez to my smart contract, I tried from the temple interface but it does not work, I think it is because it is a contract address and not a simple address of wallet... Do you know another way?

Thank you for your attention and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement the `default` entrypoint. If you're writing in CamelLIGO, here's a sample of how it would be implemented:

```
let main (param, storage : entrypoint * contract_storage) : operation list * contract_storage =
    match param with
    | Withdraw recipient ->
        let () = if Tezos.amount > 0tez
        then failwith "If you'd like to send funds; you're invoking the wrong function"
        in withdraw(recipient, storage)
    | Default _d -> ([]: operation list), storage
```

There's more discussion at https://help.sweet.io/en/articles/5884308-sending-funds-to-a-blockchain-payment-contract

Answer (score 2):

To have the same transfer behavior on `originated contracts` (KT1... addresses) as on `implicit accounts` (tz{1,2,3}... addresses), you will need to add a `default` entrypoint with `unit` input.

```
(unit %default)
```

Comment: the default (unit) parameter is represented like this in storage: { } ?

Comment: It is not in the storage. It is just an entrypoint named `default` that has `unit` as input type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SmartPy you can add the `default` entrypoint to your contract like this:

```
@sp.entry_point()
def default(self, params):
    sp.set_type(params, sp.TUnit)
```

Once that is in place your contract will be able to receive funds directly.